Imagick not working with GAE runtime php82 or php83
We have been using Imagick with Google App Engine with runtime php81 for some time.  I changed the runtime in app.yaml php83 and received the following error when testing Imagick:
Uncaught ImagickException: no decode delegate for this image format `SVG' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/363 in /workspace/...
I tried runtime php82 and received the same error.  Why is this?
I understand there may not yet be an official Imagick release for PHP 8.3, but there is for 8.2.  Yet php82 doesn't work either.  Did I do something wrong?
Thanks!
Edit: Imagick SVG to JPG error no decode delegate does not solve my problem because I am using Google App Engine and cannot manually install things like this.  Additionally, imagick.so is supposed to be available by default (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php-gen2/runtime#dynamically_loadable_extensions).  This seems to be a problem with Google App Engine.
New info: Image Magick sort of works.  I can read PNG metadata with it using runtime php82, but it cannot ingest SVG tags as it used to when it was using runtime php81.

I added "Edit:" and "New info:" after another user's comments/suggestions
